# How to make PowerShell Alias to execute a file?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I want to have this:

```
Set-Alias pr php \.fileToExecute
```

So that it runs the file in PHP (depending on where I am located when I execute `pr`).

Answer (score 6):

First create a function:

```
function RunPHP {php c:\www\phpinfo.php}
```

Then create the alias to run that function:

```
Set-Alias pr RunPHP
```

---

You probably want to run different files so the function should accept a variable as the file path:

```
function RunPHP($path) {php $path}
```

Now set the alias as shown above and you can run this command:

```
pr c:\www\file.php
```